# How to save image downloaded from picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I am currently developing an android app with takes image URls from my custom server and loads them into a ImageView. I have used Picasso for this. I have successfully completed the downloading process but how I want to save the image in the device so that the user can view them even when the app is run offline without loss in quality of image. I plan to store the image location into my database. I just need the code to save it to memory and the way to get access to that image in another class. There are exactly 5 images.

Comment: Have you tried to use the IO classes from Java?

Comment: i looked at it but i was confused about acessing the image from file from another class. it would be better from me if i could just save it in the database

Answer (score 1):

You are loading images from picasso , try this

```
@Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + url);
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                            ostream.flush();
                            ostream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }
```

It will save the loaded file in device storage.
Make sure to have write_storage permission in manifest.

Comment: how can i acess the file contents from another class? i mean accessing the image from other class

Comment: You just need url of that file

Comment: Store url of that image in some global variable, and access it in other class using object